# Google Chrome not working

Tags: 10.10, google-chrome

for some reason the Google Chrome I installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre is not working. Version number: 9.0.597.94-r73967 (google-chrome-stable). What can be wrong?

Also, what exactly is Chromium web browser? What's the difference between the two. Firefox is working fine, but I prefer Google Chrome.

Comment: for short: Chrome is Chromium re-branded and with propietary software built in it, what exactly does not work with Chrome?

Comment: The differences are outlined in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advanta

Comment: @Uri Issues resolved - thanks. I was used to only have to change the proxy settings in IE. Seems to me in ubuntu you need to change it for all browsers. @Jorge - sorry for asking again! While I tried to resolve the issue myself I saw Chromium on the software centre and was just wondering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "non working"? 
What's the issue you experience? 
Chromium and Google Chrome is *almost* the same by the way. Chromium is an open source software, and usually not as stable as Google Chrome. Google releases Chrome based on Chromium regularly. Chrome itself is not entirely an open source software, it contains some not-free pieces as well. Chromium is mainly for developers, but for sure, someone can install it to use ... There are different channels for Chromium, such as snapshots and more stable but less regular versions, it's up to you what you use.

Comment: Thank, I'm quite sure I know the difference between Chrome and Chromium now - thanks for that :) What I mean with "not working" is this: I will type in a url in the address bar, but it don't go past "send request..." In the end - after roughly 2 minutes - it will say: 

This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://www.facebook.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Comment: are you using a proxy?

Comment: The question has this part too: "Also, what exactly is Chromium web browser? What's the difference between the two", I answered for that part with my description. Hmm, this issue seems to be connection related, if you start another web browser on the same machine, does it work? If yes, is it possible that you're using proxy or so with the working browser, but not with the other?

Comment: Yap, I got that one too :) The "what is Chromium" answer. I'm using a proxy yes. I'm actually on firefox now - on the same system. So the problem has to be with Chrome. Ok, wait, maybe not. I'm on an University network. In Windows 7 you only have to change the LAN settings in IE for Internet to work on any browser... RESOLVED! Thanks. I changed the proxy setting in Chrome as well - everything is working fine now. Thank you so much!