# Google-Chrome 10 stable crash on every page

Tags: google-chrome

I installed google-chrome today, when i open any page including askubuntu i got this error message.

[image: google-chrome]

i see my memory usage is normal(Memory 56% and swap 4.8%) also I reload and i go to another page same problem 
What is the problem?

the last `dmesg` output

```
[26612.341865] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions 
[29651.852476] chrome[15472] general protection ip:1528e26 sp:7fff514a9dc0 error:0 in chrome[400000+3082000] 
[31447.190586] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1c:25:a1:e7:67:00:16:3e:28:5a:b7:08:00 SRC=172.23.100.6 DST=172.23.20.128 LEN=69 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15939 PROTO=UDP SPT=4243 DPT=161 LEN=49  
[31451.250190] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1c:25:a1:e7:67:00:16:3e:28:5a:b7:08:00 SRC=172.23.100.6 DST=172.23.20.128 LEN=69 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=16180 PROTO=UDP SPT=4243 DPT=161 LEN=49  
[31454.260150] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1c:25:a1:e7:67:00:16:3e:28:5a:b7:08:00 SRC=172.23.100.6 DST=172.23.20.128 LEN=69 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=16322 PROTO=UDP SPT=4243 DPT=161 LEN=49  
[31458.648164] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1c:25:a1:e7:67:00:16:3e:28:5a:b7:08:00 SRC=172.23.100.6 DST=172.23.20.128
LEN=69 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=16513 PROTO=UDP SPT=4243 DPT=161 LEN=49  
[33124.300112] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions 
[33601.021406] Skipping EDID probe due to cached edid 
[34594.043501] chrome[15746]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000d5cdd0 sp 00007fff5149ec20 error 6 in chrome[400000+3082000] 
[34597.395334] chrome[18112] general protection ip:17c85bf sp:7fff514aa4f0 error:0 in chrome[400000+3082000] 
[34616.786643] chrome[18124]: segfault at 1007 ip 00000000017c849f sp 00007fff514aabd0 error 4 in chrome[400000+3082000] 
[37277.436207] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions 
[38549.501390] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Down 
[38551.122253] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX 
[38551.122263] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Comment: Did you mean `chromium-browser` or Google Chrome? Looks like the browser ran out of memory, what is the RAM size? Can you post the last lines of `dmesg`?

Comment: Google Chrome 10 is `Beta` and not stable. Google Chrome 9 is `Stable`. If this is chromium then I am not sure. BTW please tell from where you installed this. `Google Chrome PPA` for Chrome or from `Official repos` for Chromium

Comment: @Lekensteyn  i mean Google-chrome  i have update the first post with dmesg output                                          @Manish Sinha i hope it is stable did you see this news http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Google-releases-Chrome-10-stable-improves-JavaScript-performance-1204493.html  i downloaded from google site here: http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux_ubuntu_x86_64

Comment: Can you try the open source browser `chromium-browser` instead of Google Chrome? Debugging closed-source applications is more difficult. Install `chromium-browser` by issuing `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. You might want to remove google-chrome first. For the differences between google chrome and chromium, see [What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6253/6969).

Comment: I'll add it as answer, not everyone is reading these comments.

Comment: Am actually using Google Chrome 10 Final Release which came out 2 days ago. No problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome is closed source. That makes it more difficult to debug the program compared to open source applications.

Uninstall `google-chrome` and install the open source browser `chromium-browser` instead:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

`google-chrome` will clean itself up by removing their repository from apt.

There are [some](https://askubuntu.com/q/6253/6969) differences between the proprietary Google Chrome and Chromium Browser, but I have not missed any features yet.