# Can't update Google Chrome

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I updated Google Chrome from the Software Updater in Ubuntu 12.04, but it didn't actually update. "About Google Chrome " is still showing the previous release.

Comment: Chris, what version number are you seeing?

Comment: Here is more discussion on the subject:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/886190/gmail-is-showing-this-version-of-chrome-is-no-longer-supported

Answer (score 30):

If you would like to keep you browser up to date, I think the easiest thing to do is to add the PPA. I will explain how to do this for both Chrome and Chromium. These two browsers are mostly the same, but you can check out the differences [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant).

**Chrome**

First you have to install the key. This can be done by opening Terminal and typing

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Step two is to add the repository

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'`

Then you update and, if you haven't already, install Google Chrome

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

**Chromium**

Chromium is more straight forward. Just add the PPA, update, and install by typing this in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: thank you. it works on my ubuntu 18.0

Comment: after doing this I also had to go the Chrome -> Settings > About Chrome and re-launch (it doesn't work if you just close and start Chrome)

Comment: did not work for me, having added the key and repo, it still said `Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable`

Comment: I am getting this warning for the chrome first option: Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 because `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` was automatically disabled. I changed it from this
`# deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to jammy`
to this
`deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`
and it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for Ubuntu 14 (end of 2015!): Chrome refused to update although all the required updates were done. The reason seems to be that there's still some background processes running even though Chrome is closed.

Close Chrome and just look up all "chrome" entries in 'top' and do 'kill 12345' where 12345 is the PID of each 'chrome' process. Then start the browser.

Comment: You should also be able to do a `pkill chrome` to get all the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest deb.

[Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)

Install it.It will add repository to your software source. After that you can update it via terminal when a update pack release. Via command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` does not install software updates. It updates the information about what software is available (including updated versions) and from where. To actually update the software (i.e., to *upgrade* packages to newly available versions), run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`. You may want to edit your answer to incorporate this information.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue when upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 18.04. Chrome fails to auto-update.

Similar to answer from bb1950328 but with different file in which I had to uncomment repo:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

> ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
> # You may comment outthis entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
>
> #deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

To

> ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ### # You may comment out
> this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
>
> deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

after this change update and upgrade works also for chrome:

```
sudo apt-get update  && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following command in your terminal as it is:

```
google-chrome --version

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

Again check for the version and restart your chrome:

```
google-chrome --version
```

Tada! It might be helpful to you.
I stuck in updating since long time it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to H. Arponen's answer, my problem was caused by not closing down all instances of the previous version. However, mine was more different because I did not have any actual normal Chrome instances running, but I had a Chrome app running ([Signal IM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms&hl=en)).

Versions:

- Linux Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04)
- Chrome 52/58
- Installed via `apt` (`apt-get`)
- Signal 0.38.2