# Gmail is showing "This version of Chrome is no longer supported"

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, update-manager, chromium, gmail

Recently I received this message when I opened Gmail in the Chromium Browser on Ubuntu 14.04 ->

[image]

I searched the web and found [this article](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2017/02/gmail-no-longer-support-chrome-53/) (and many other more) which informed me about the recent Google policy that Gmail will stop supporting Chrome 53 and below. So, I checked the version of the Chromium browser I have installed:

[image]

Now I want to upgrade the Chromium browser to one of the latest Chrome versions 55 or 56, but I am not able to do that. The Software Updater is showing me that my PC is updated. So, what to do next?
I know that I can switch to Mozilla Firefox, but I still want to use Chromium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update google chrome](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157452/cant-update-google-chrome)

Comment: Why should I add the PPA as told in your link? I installed Chromium form Software Center and till now I never faced any updating issues. It updates automatically. I think this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Looks like they stopped at 53. Check https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/chromium-browser.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas You can use Firefox if you don't want to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak yes, looks like you are right :(

Comment: You didn't install Chrome, you installed *Chromium*. There's no Chrome in Canonical's software repositories.

Comment: Firefox is preinstalled in 14.05 - note that it will not import my dozens of categorized Chromuim bookmarks directly, but it will import from a Chromium HTML bookmarks export file. It comes in at All Bookmarks/Bookmarks Menu/Bookmarks Bar - so you navigate there then click on the right side, do a Ctrl-A and drag them up to Bookmarks Toolbar to get them to show. And surprise, Lastpass now supports Firefox. But Tunnelbear still will not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running Ubuntu 14.04 as to be seen from the 'tag' in your question. This system is about three years old and the repositories provide the [chromium-browser 53.0.2785.143](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/chromium-browser) package. So, you should consider to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it provides the [chromium-browser 55.0.2883.87](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/chromium-browser) package, which most probably will get updated for some longer time - at least until the next LTS edition gets released.

Comment: It looks like there are some problems to update chromium further on 14.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is the current version of chromium on your 16.04 pc ?

Comment: I have `55.0.2883.87` It is easy to find out by http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: ok. thanks. looks like I need os up gradation.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Good idea ... absolutely recommended also for the reason of other improvements. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox yes, i will accept your answer, and I hope you will like my question too..

Comment: 14.04 is supposed to be supported until 2019, how come security updates such as this weren't ported? If a LTS stops being supported when the next LTS gets released... that kinda defeats the purpose of being a LTS in the first place, no?

Comment: @T.Verron Chromium is is not part of the official Ubuntu system release, hence the packages are not in the main repository. The package `chromium-browser` is in the universe repository, which means that it gets updated by volunteers, not by Canonical. :)

Comment: Thanks for the precision. That's still a problem with the LTS, even if it is not canonical's fault. Especially considering that there is no ppa (afai can find) providing the current stable version of chromium.

Comment: When my 14.04 system helpfully offered to upgrade to 16 I let it try.  It never came back alive after that, untill I restored the backup.  So I will gladly "Dismiss" that warning if that's the price to pay for having a stable system.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up **Chrome** and **Chromium**.  You suggest you want to update to the lastest version of Chrome, but you are showing images that shows you are running Chrominium.  They are different browsers.  The latest version release of the browsers are not the same.  The browser number of Chrome is higher than the browser number of Chromium.

You can download and install Chrome by going to http://www.google.com/chrome/ and browsing to the download option.

Just as your Chromium provides automatic updates, your Googe-Chrome browser will do the same, keeping up automatically updated to the latest features and security updates.

You are running Chrome on your Windows PC, not Chromium.  You can have the same version of Chrome on your Ubuntu OS by installing Chrome.  This is what you did for your Windows PC.

**Note**:
The automatic updates (for Chromium) that you reference in the comments are for the repository of your (still supported Ubuntu 14.04).  While it's still supported, some of the applications might be outdated,and the updates may not have made it to the official 14.04 repository.  For that reason, to have the latest version of the applications that haven't made it to the repository, you would have to install the PPA for that application.  This is why you see a link to a PPS for updating Chromium.

Comment: I think OP does not mix them up. If it is a 32-bit system, Chrome is not available at all. And I am not sure new version of Chrome will install to 14.04 either.

Comment: Yes, my os is 32 bit. actually my plan is to completely remove this 14.04 32-bit os once 18.04 64-bit is available. but if I face such problem then I should change my plan and will update to 16.04 32-bit

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't realize the OP had a 32-bit system.  There wasn't a reference.  The latest version of Chrome works on 14.04.  As I mentioned in the answer, once installed, it'll continue to automatically update to the latest version.  So far the version Chrome support has lasted the live of a Ubuntu LTS cycle.

Comment: Chrome is no longer available for any LInux 32 bit system.  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued

Comment: @OrganicMarble Of course.  It's  common knowledge.  My ecommendation would have been for the OP to either use a PPA or upgrade to 16.04LTS for Chromium.  Chrome and Chromium were referenced as if they were interchangeable the same.  I saw fit to point out they weren't and the best solution for running the save version of Chrome in both OS'.  I didn't infer a reason for not installing Chrome.  The question appeared as if it were installed.  The details may help others having similar problems when they think they are running Chrome.  Years ago I thought they were both from Google also.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the information update of the 32bit OS version.

Comment: Your link to www.Google.com just goes to the search engine.  I suspect you mean http://chrome.google.com - and when you go there and try, I say try, to install Chrome, it has the same problem.  Opera takes some fitzing to get installed, but it works fine.  But nothing from Google seems to work.  I have two production Linux machines coordinating a bunch of Rpis.  One is 12.04 and the other is 14.04 - and upgrading the 14 system to 16 killed it, so thank goodness for backups.  Basically, I'm left having to "Dismiss" that dumb warning at first use of Chromium, but otherwise it seems to work fine.

Comment: Please notice that I gave the Company name and the company's main website, specifying the difference between Chromium which the user was mistaking as an authorized (by Google) version of Chrome.  I intentionally picked the main site and gave a description to browse to the download section to get the actual Google Chrome browser.  In view of your comment, I'll add steps to where to find the Chrome download on the site.