# Is there any advantage of using Google Chrome over Chromium?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

I haven't tried Chrome yet on Ubuntu 12.04, I am a little worried about privacy issues, but other than that, what would Google Chrome have that Chromium does not provide? Does Google Chrome run great on Ubuntu?

Comment: **Duplicate**: http://askubuntu.com/q/6253/43660