# Change Google Chrome language?

Tags: google-chrome, language-support

Today I installed the new Ubuntu 12.10 (fresh install) and I noticed that Google Chrome was in the wrong language. I am Portuguese, from Portugal, and Google Chrome is now on Brazilian Portuguese (which is kind of annoying).

I had this problem before, but downloading the DVD edition of the OS would fix the problem (Google Chrome would be in PT-PT on a DVD installation).

The problem is that Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't have a DVD specific edition... So, how can I manualy change Google Chrome's language?

Comment: Can you check to see what language is set as default for your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: It's Portuguese(Portugal)...

Answer (score 6):

In your `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome-stable.desktop` change the "exec" command to something like this:

```
Exec=sh -c "export LANGUAGE=pt_BR.UTF-8 && /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U &"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer worked perfectly fine. BTW, it's actually sufficient to just supply LANGUAGE as a local variable, e.g. `sh -c "LANGUAGE=en /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U"`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of downloading the Portuguese version from here: https://www.google.pt/intl/pt/chrome/browser/

Alternatively you can use Chromium ([see differences between Chrome and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)) and download it from the software center. I'm pretty sure it will automatically be in the system language, so in your case Portuguese-Portuguese.

Comment: I did. Chrome will be in Portuguese (Brazilian) even if downloaded from the Portuguese site. This is a issue that happened to me on every CD version of Ubuntu (downloading the DVD would fix the problem). But there isn't a DVD version for quantal...

Comment: Alright. I've read up on it and I think it's intentional as [Brazilian-Portuguese and Portuguese-Portuguese are the same now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Language_Orthographic_Agreement_of_1990): "This spelling reform went into effect in Brazil on January 1, 2009. In Portugal, the reform was signed into law by the President on July 21, 2008 allowing for a 6-year adaptation period, during which both orthographies will co-exist". I guess Google thought it was time to make the change.

Comment: Well, they are doing wrong again. The two languages are VERY different from each other... The orthography agreement was just for words that were written differently, not the way they are used. Whatever, I'll just stick with Precise for now.

Comment: sorry to not be of much help. if i were you i'd give chromium a try!

Comment: I tried  chromium. PT-BR as well xD

Comment: i also confirm that Chromium keep defining pt-BR instead of pt-PT. this is also a problem because all search engines search for Brazilian links not Portuguese.