# How can I install Chromium development?

Tags: chromium, software-installation

http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

32 bit deb I get is Chrome not Chromium!

Where can I install Chromium dev not Chrome dev??

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of Chromium dev channels, the project only provides source code for other people to build Chromium, they don't offer Chromium as an end user testable tarball.

You can however build it from source:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions

See also:

- [What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

Comment: How did I download amd64 .deb week ago?I didnt have to build anything! The dev chromium is still used on my amd pc how do you explain now?

Comment: I would like to build the latest possible version but my PC is too weak according to this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructionsPrerequisites

Comment: Perhaps you grabbed it from a PPA or something like this? https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-dev

Comment: proof you are wrong! http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: how do you explain now?

Comment: As you explained in your question, those aren't chromium debs, they are chrome debs.

Comment: this is chromium website not google chrome.It worked week ago!

Comment: @PriceSave it says "Chrome Release Channels" not chromimum... as for a week - even a month ago it was the same - http://web.archive.org/web/20140104171952/http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: @JorgeCastro weird it says chromium at top of that.Somehow I installed chromium though!

Comment: @PriceSave Chromium is in the repos and I'm sure there is a PPA. There is no Chromium dev however.