# not able to install google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

i have tried all the answers on this site but it doesnt help nothing works and
it gives this following error:

```
Unpacking google-chrome-stable:i386 (from .../google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:i386:google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2).
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable:i386 (--install):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

Does someone has ay clue ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: in linux you do not feel the difference between chrome and chromium and the latter does not have google EULA associated.

Comment: sudo gdebi filename.deb

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Just [install Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) and under the apps tab, you will find a link to install Google Chrome directly.

---

**EDIT**

Check images below:

[image]

[image]

Though now in your case, you will have to check the checkbox and then click install.
Hope it works out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded a .deb package containing Chrome and try to install it by doing a `sudo dpkg -i <my deb file>`, the command **dpkg** will not be able to handle the dependencies. In your case, you will have to manually install the `xdg-utils` package prior to installing your Chrome package :

```
$ sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
```

then

```
$ sudo dpkg -i <chrome deb package>
```

Or as said by many others you simply install `chromium` with `apt-get` from the default Ubuntu repository, managing automatically all the dependencies. You will have the advantage to be able to easily update to new releases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead [Google Chrome which not that different compare to the open source project Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/a/6257/93232) You should intall the free version of Chrome, using the command

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to install an x86 package on a x64 machine. Is it true? 
If so, you should download and install the x64 version.