# Google Chrome install problem

Tags: google-chrome

My computer is a Lenovo IdeaPad U410 Touch with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to  install Chrome.
When I tried to install Google Chrome I was asked what download package to choose:

```
32 bit deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)
64 bit deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)
32 bit rpm (for Fedora/openSUSE)
64 bit rpm (for Fedora/openSUSE)
```

So what should I choose?

Comment: Visit http://askubuntu.com/q/41332/ to know your installed OS type.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there is the Chromium-browser package, which is available in the software repository, or installed by:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

The main [difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant) between Chromium-browser and Chrome is that the former is an community maintained version of Chrome.

As a result of this ([among other things](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome)) the proprietary Flash plug-in included in Chrome is not included in Chromium, altough you can enable this during intallation or afterwards by installing the [pepperflash plugin.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/pepperflashplugin-nonfree) [image: Install banshee]

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs of your system, most likely you have Ubuntu 64bit installed, so you can install the 64bit deb file for Ubuntu.

To check which version of Ubuntu is installed on your machine, see [Checking your Ubuntu Version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion)

Or

You can install  google chrome in ubuntu this way,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome
```

Comment: To clarify - there is no thing as official Google Chrome PPA. PPA is an acronime for Personal Package Archive and is directly connected with Launchpad.net.

Comment: @enedil see http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome

Comment: If a third site says that it's PPA, it does not mean it is a PPA.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/510186/256099

Comment: @enedil you're missing the point.  Whether its called a PPA or not, its a good way to install Chrome in Ubuntu

Comment: I just wrote "to clarify". I got a habit of using precise language whenever it does not annoy.

Comment: I understand, the point is to help the OP solve his issue.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should choose

```
64 bit deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)
```

Just double-click on downloaded file and follow istructions.

As @Mitch mentioned, there is Google Chrome repository, but after installation of Google Chrome from this package, you'll have repository added. No need for the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
uname -i
```

The output will indicate **x86_64** for 64 bit Debian/Ubuntu or **i386** for 32 bit Debian/Ubuntu.

---

**First**,

to download the **x86_64** bit version, open a terminal and type:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Then**,

to install the **x86_64** bit version, type:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

---

**Or**,

use these two commands to install the i386 or 32bit version instead:

```
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```