# How to install google chrome manually in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu in Windows through VMware software.
In windows we have `*.exe` file to install any software, for Ubuntu how to install google chrome or any software manually, without using Terminal?

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)** If there are multiple answers that solve your problem please pick the best one.

Comment: Just install **Chromium**, the open-source (FLOSS) counterpart to Chrome. Basically Google develops Chromium, adds some proprietary features (and likely tracking features) to it and distributes it as "Chrome".  
So either install Chromium from the software center or just `sudo apt-get install chromium`. I think that's way easier to install!

See also: [What's the difference between Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer:

To install software manually you will most likely need to download a `.deb` file (it's sort of Ubuntu's `.msi` equivalent), and then either:

1. Double-click it and install it through the Ubuntu Software Center.

Or:

2. Use the command-line (I will explain both).

### Long answer:

Download Google Chrome [**here**](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and click:

[image: Button]

In order to download the `.deb` installation file.

It will likely ask you if you want the 32-bit or 64-bit one, download whichever is [appropriate for your install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os), and accept the license agreement.

**GUI Installation:**

When the download is complete, open your file manager (probably Nautilus) and navigate to the location where you downloaded the file to (probably the `~/Downloads` folder).

Then double-click the file, this should open the Ubuntu Software Center, to install click the <kbd>Install</kbd> button and then enter your password as prompted (your Ubuntu Software Center may look slightly different to mine in terms of design as I am on the GNOME flavour of Ubuntu):

[image: Software center]

In the above screenshot I have put a red box around the `Install` button you need to press.

**Terminal Installation:**

Now for the command-line Terminal installation, first open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), then use the `cd` command to navigate to the location you downloaded the file to. You will probably need to go to the `~/Downloads` folder with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

And then you will need to run the following command to install Google Chrome where you need to replace `[filename] with the name of the file you downloaded. (Either` google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`(64-bit) or`google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` (32-bit) ):

```
sudo dpkg -i [filename]
```

You will then be prompted for your password (though you will notice that even though it does not look like you are typing anything, in fact you are and this is just a security feature), enter the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and that should install Google Chrome.

Comment: Actually, the `.deb` is equivalent to `.msi` files and `.exe` self-contained compressed files with a `setup.exe` that auto-runs upon extraction.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Ok, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The command line method is the easiest way to install Google Chrome,
but below you can find other methods as well, so you are free to choose.

---

### Google Chrome PPA (recommended)

Using the PPA you will be able to update Google Chrome easily using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or when performing the upgrade process by using the Ubuntu Software Center.

When the system is configured to automatic update you don't have to care about anything at all.

#### Command line method

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

---

#### GUI method :

1. Open your dash:

   [image: Dash]

   and type `Software and Updates`, go to the <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab and select <kbd>Add...</kbd>.
2. Add the following line :

   ```
   deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
   ```

   [image: Software properties]
3. Click <kbd>Add Source</kbd> and enter your password.
4. Select <kbd>Close</kbd> and click <kbd>Reload</kbd> on this screen :

   [image]
5. Open Ubuntu Software Center, search for `google-chrome`, click <kbd>Install</kbd> and you are done.

---

### Without PPA (easiest method)

#### Command line method :

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

**For 64 bit systems:**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**For 32 bit systems:**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

---

#### Graphical method :

Download Google Chrome from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) and double click the `.deb` in file manager to install Google Chrome using your favorite package manager (Ubuntu Software Center by default).

Answer (score 1):

the most simple way would be downloading `.deb` of Google Chrome from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/index.html). Don't worry about ppa it will take care of it. You can keep the `.deb` file for later use too.

*it is equivalent to windows' `.exe` for Ubuntu*

Comment: A DEB matches a Windows MSI more than a Windows EXE. Shell-script installers fit the bill of exe more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Software Center for most software. You'll find Chromium in there. However, Chromium is the "open source version" of Google Chrome, not Google Chrome itself. You'll have to download a file from the Google Chrome website and open it. This'll load the software center which will allow you to install it.

Since you're new to this page: Please press the tick on the left it this solves your problem.