# Hi guys am new user of ubuntu can any one guide how to install chrome

Tags: 14.04

steps for installing chrome
Hi guys am new user of ubuntu can any one guide how to install chrome

Comment: Please note that there is Open Source **Chromium** you can easily install from the Software Center. For minor differences to Chrome see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant

Answer (score 3):

Visit https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Download, clicking at 64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)

It will recognize you're coming from ubuntu and offer an installation package x32 or x64.deb, depending on the hardwarde and type of 14.04 you have (this you can check by typing uname -a in the terminal and see the output x64 or x32.) but most likely you're using 64.

After that just open the package you downloaded and follow instructions.

Finally, open the dash in unity and type chrome to find it. When you open it, you could also right-click the icon in the laucher and select "lock to launcher" for easier starting.

**OR**
Alternatively, you could install through the command line in terminal.

Press CTRL+ALT+T to open the terminal. Type (line after line):

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```